# Compile SD file in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, service-definition

Is there a way to build Service Definition files in Pro? I assume not since they have everything on lockdown to Portal. Thought I would ask here though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build .SD (service definition files) in ArcGIS Pro. Only using Python, no "GUI" way to do it.

See [CreateWebLayerSDDraft](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/createweblayersddraft.htm) command.

Following the building of the SDDraft and Staging into a SD, you'd use the Upload Tool using the proper key word (**My Hosted Services**) to share the .SD file to your portal that you've authenticated too.

Comment: Interesting! Can I assume it will still require Portal or Online to use? Still a no-go for Server?

Comment: @Midavalo I haven't tested every service type that has a Create_X_SDDraft command, but for this one in particular, CreateWebLayer, I'm almost positive it only works with MY_HOSTED_SERVICES as the server type, as such, when using the UploadTool, only to My Hosted Services (Portal) - this command only exists in Pro. The other commands which exist at 10.x and Pro may work directly to Server, you'd need to experiment to know. (Although I'd say that it wouldnt be officially supported)

Answer (score 1):

No.

> ArcMap publishes data to ArcGIS Server to create web services. ArcGIS Pro shares content to a portal (ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS) and can create a web map, web scene, web layers, and their associated web services.

Therefore you would need to use this functionality to publish from ArcGIS Pro.

See [this reponse](https://community.esri.com/ideas/12258#comment-50543) from Esri's Derek Law on the Geonet forums, and his linked [UC Q&A](http://www.esri.com/about/events/uc/get-involved/q-and-a#id=1233) (you may need to scroll down to see the Q&A answer, but it should be highlighted on that page).

Answer (score 0):

Thought I should update with a new feature in Arcgis Pro. This can be done with arcpy, and there is a simple way in the GUI right click layer, save as a service definition file (portal or standalone server)